# Change TextInput type="date" format in react-materialize

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I need to change the TextInput type="date" display/input format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy, I don't care if it is stored as YYYY-MM-DD, but I care about how it displays the input itself.

```
<TextInput 
 label="Date Label"  
 type="date" 
 value={myDate} 
 onChange={e => setMyDate(e.target.value)}
/>
```

I'm not using the full datepicker, I'm only setting the TextInput to type date.

Answer (score 0):

A TextInput of type date is going to render a input with type date. Inputs of type date show the date in a format based on the locale of the user's browser.  This allows dates to be displayed in the format expected by the user and you should not alter this behavior.